# What is the substitue for Resteasy ProxyFactory class

Tags: java, resteasy

I just realized that the `ProxyFactory` class is marked deprecated in RestEasy version 3.0.0. Sadly the approach that deprecates this class is not documented anywhere. I used to initialize my services this way but what is the new way?

```
protected static final String URL = "http://localhost:12345"+"/api";
protected static final MyService myService = ProxyFactory.create(MyService.class, URL);
```

Comment: I found this [link](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.2.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html#d4e2076). Section 46.2 seems to answer your question, does it?

Comment: Would be good but those classes don't exist in Resteasy 3.0.0. The JAXRS API 3.0.0 is also added but that has only a ClientBuilder and I can't get a proxy out of it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

RESTEasy 3.0.2.Final ( http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/08/03/jax-rs-2-0-resteasy-3-0-2-final-client-api-example/ )

```
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();

ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(URL);

MyService myService = target.proxy(MyService .class);
```

Comment: Is this thread-safe?? what about in this case??

String url = "http://localhost:12345"+"/api";
MyService myService = ProxyFactory.create(MyService.class, url, clientExecutor);